# Download Google Drive File from Excel Sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, google-drive-api

The hyperlink below appears in a cell in an Excel Sheet. It opens and displays a file if clicked on (permissions given to anyone with the link)

How can I download a linked file to a local folder using Excel vba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### URLDownloadToFile on Google Drive

- The folder `C:\Test` has to exist for this example to work.
- For more info on `URLDownloadToFile` try to search [`SO`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bvba%5d%20URLDownloadToFile) or `Google`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
        Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
        ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
        Alias "URLDownLoadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If

Function downloadFile( _
    ByVal FileURL As String, _
    ByVal FilePath As String) _
As Boolean
    Const ProcName As String = "downloadFile"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    URLDownloadToFile 0, FileURL, FilePath, 0, 0
    downloadFile = True

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Sub downloadGoogleDrive()
    
    Const UrlLeft As String = "http://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id="
    Const UrlRight As String = "&export=download"
    
    Const FileID As String = "17bw2KgzD1ifcA7rdXdxiN9bN70g8jnMO"
    Const FilePath As String _
        = "C:\Test\Type1 and Type 2 errors - Atyati Temp.jpg"
    
    Dim Url As String: Url = UrlLeft & FileID & UrlRight
    
    Dim wasDownloaded As Boolean
    wasDownloaded = downloadFile(Url, FilePath)
    If wasDownloaded Then
        MsgBox "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "Fail"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a Ton. It is working. Will need to adapt it to my context by writing a loop etc.

Comment: Is there a way I can download the file with the original name as in the google drive instead of renaming it ie. save the file to the local folder with the original name instead of specifying the name in the FilePath variable

Comment: Not that I know of. But click the SO link and read through some solutions, maybe there is a way. Also, there is another solution to download using `xhr` and `ADODB` but I couldn't get it to work with this link.

Comment: Will try the SO Link for possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**Download File from Google Drive with original file name**

```
Sub DownloadGoogleDriveWithFilename()
Dim myOriginalURL As String
Dim myURL As String
Dim FileID As String
Dim xmlhttp As Object
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim name0 As Variant
Dim oStream As Object
Dim wasDownloaded As Boolean
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ''URL from share link or Google sheet URL or Google doc URL
    myOriginalURL = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MnaC9-adPeEjkv7AEARchoYLLSWELBsy/view?usp=sharing"
    FileID = Split(myOriginalURL, "/d/")(1) ''split after "/d/"
    FileID = Split(FileID, "/")(0)  ''split before "/"
Const UrlLeft As String = "http://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id="
Const UrlRight As String = "&export=download"
    myURL = UrlLeft & FileID & UrlRight
Debug.Print myURL
        Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
        xmlhttp.Open "GET", myURL, False  ', "username", "password"
        xmlhttp.Send

        name0 = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition")
        If name0 = "" Then
            MsgBox "file name not found"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        Debug.Print name0
        name0 = Split(name0, "=""")(1) ''split after "=""
        name0 = Split(name0, """;")(0)  ''split before "";"
'        name0 = Replace(name0, """", "") ' Remove double quotes
        Debug.Print name0

        FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.path
        FilePath = FolderPath & "\" & name0
      
 ''This part is equvualent to URLDownloadToFile(0, myURL, FolderPath & "\" & name0, 0, 0)
 ''just without having to write Windows API code for 32 bit and 64 bit.
    If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write xmlhttp.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile FilePath, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If
    
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
  If FileExists(FilePath) Then
        wasDownloaded = True
        ''open folder path location to look at the downloded file
        Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & FolderPath, vbNormalFocus)
  Else
        wasDownloaded = False
        MsgBox "failed"
  End If
End Sub

Function FileExists(FilePath As String) As Boolean
Dim TestStr As String
    TestStr = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TestStr = "" Then
        FileExists = False
    Else
        FileExists = True
    End If
End Function
```